# identify non Latin Charset text Ph

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

From a huge text file , Need to be able to identify lines that contains non Latin characters (\w plus Special characters) technically i should exclude other alphabets than Latin. the output is stored in a log file for further processing.
my attempts with `re` have not been successful, do you see an smart way to identify and exude the lines containing non Latin characters.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
pattern = '^\w+$'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
filename = "C:\\ImportTool\\import\\file.csv"
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as inputfile, \
     open(filename + '.clean', 'w', encoding="utf8") as outputfile, \
     open(filename + '.special', 'w', encoding="utf8") as outputfile_log:
        for index, line in enumerate(inputfile):
            #print(index, (line_aux[:]))
            if  (regex.search(line) == None):
                outputfile.writelines(line)
            else:
                outputfile_log.writelines(line)
```

I.e Below line should be excluded since contents Hebraic

```
"100";"xxxxxxxxx";"00002";"ZM";"B";"";"";"B";"R";"R";"X";"RR";"I02";"OxxH";"20161107";"ybatuca";"זמניים מחלקת תיפעול חיפה";"";"";"IL01";"";"";"";"";"1000.000 "
```

Comment: The problem with your search is that `\w` matches only a small subset of characters used in latin-based languages — the word characters. Do you want to exclude all lines that contain non-latin alphabetic characters, or do you want to exclude all lines that don't contain latin alphabetic characters?

Comment: I want to exclude all lines that contain non-latin alphabetic characters

Comment: are you looking for `\pL` characters???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python contains the `unicodedata` module for things like that:

```
import unicodedata
...

for index, line in enumerate(inputfile):
    if any(unicodedata.category(ch).startswith("L") and not unicodedata.name(ch).startswith("LATIN")):
        ...  # contains non-latin alphabetic chars
    else:
        ...  # doesn't contain non-latin alphabetic chars
```